# hard conditional probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

It is known that a woman has $7$ children and $2$ of them are girls , the rest is unknown.

a-) What is the probability that the intermediate child is boy (intemediate boy means it is in amid when they ordered as to their ages)

b-)What is the probability that woman has  three boys

I know that it is conditional probability question but i stuck in it.I do not even how to calculate "a woman has $7$ children and $2$ of them are girls , the rest is unknown."

Can you help me to handle this question.

Comment: Part b can be done without a conditional probability.  What is the probability that 3 or more of the 5 remaining children would be boys?  And part A would be 1/2 if it wasn't for the 2 girls already known.

Comment: *a woman has 7 children and 2 of them are girls*.  Does this signify **at least** 2 of them are girls or **exactly** 2 of them are girls?  In part (a) what does the phrase *the intermediate boy* represent, **exactly**, with respect to the ages of the **seven** children?  In part (b), does the phrase *woman has 3 boys* represent **at least** three boys, or **exactly** three boys?

Comment: @IanJ I think that your assertion is unclear.  Among the many problems that the question, as presented has, re my previous comment, assume that the woman does have *at least* two girls.  How was this determined?  If (for example) all of the children were gathered into a room, the genders were counted, and it was found that there are less than 6 boys, then okay.  Alternatively, if (for example) two random children were selected, and both of these randomly inspected children were seen to be girls, then you can't escape Bayes theorem, and the answer to part (b) will definitely be different.

Comment: Give the two known girls for adoption and ask the questions about five children.

Comment: @herbsteinberg have I made a mistake?  Do you disagree with the distinction between randomly inspecting only two genders and inspecting all the genders at once?

Comment: My interpretation is that all are inspected, but we are told only that the number of girls is at least two.

Comment: @herbsteinberg fair interpretation, and probably does represent the intent of the problem composer.  However, my point still stands.  Since the problem composer left the method of determination unspecified, this is another ambiguity in the problem.  I left an answer showing the effect of the (*improbable* ?) interpretation.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Also, I disagree with the *give two girls up for adoption* approach.  As I see it, of the $(2^7)$ possibilities in the binomial distribution of 7 children, only 8 have been eliminated.  Therefore, instead of the chances of at least 3 boys being $(1/2)$, I make it $\left(\frac{1}{128 - 8}\right) \times (21 + 35 + 35).$

Comment: @user2661923  I see your point.

Comment: @user2661923 - I see your point.  If it was phrased - "Two kids picked at random are girls" then you could do it my way, but otherwise you have to do conditional probability.

Comment: @IanJ No, it is vice versa.  If it was phrased "two kids picked at random are girls", then you would **have to** do it using conditional probability.  If it was phrased, "all of the children were inspected simultaneously, and it was found that there were less than 6 boys", then you would **have to** do it **without** conditional probability.  Since the method of determining the genders is left unspecified by the problem composer, you have a critical ambiguity which indicates that it is unknown what the appropriate calculation method is.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(\textrm{Boy in the middle})=\sum_{n=2}^6P(\textrm{Boy in the middle}|\textrm{#Girls}=n)P(\textrm{#Girls}=n)$$

Assume two girls and five boys. Total arrangements: $\frac{7!}{2!5!}$
Arrangements in which the middle one is a boy: $\frac{6!}{2!4!}$
For the *additional* girls, the probability is binomial with success probability $p=0.5$ and trials $N=5$. So in the end

$$P=\sum_{n=2}^6\left(\frac{7!}{n!(7-n)!}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{6!}{n!(7-n-1)!}\right)\binom{5}{n-2}0.5^{n-2}0.5^{5-(n-2)}$$

Comment: Result $\approx 0.3571$

Comment: Monte Carlo seems to confirm this

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_k$, for $k\in\{1,\ldots,5\}$, a list of independent Bernoulli r.v. with probability $p=1/2$ each one, such that $X_k=0$ if the $k$-th kid is a boy, and $X_k=1$ if it is a girl.

Then for part a) we want to calculate $\Pr [X_3=0|\sum_{k=1}^5X_k\geqslant 2]$, this gives

$$
\Pr \left[X_3=0\bigg |\sum_{k=1}^5X_k\geqslant 2\right]=\frac1{\Pr \left[\sum_{k=1}^5X_k\geqslant 2\right]}\cdot \Pr \left[\{X_3=0\}\cap \left\{\sum_{k=1}^5X_k\geqslant 2\right\}\right]\\
=\frac1{\Pr \left[\sum_{k=1}^5X_k\geqslant 2\right]}\cdot \Pr \left[\sum_{k=1}^4X_k\geqslant 2\right]
$$

And for b) you want to calculate $\Pr \left[\sum_{k=1}^5 X_k=2|\sum_{k=1}^5 X_k\geqslant 2\right]$.

I leave to you the remaining calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Followup to my comments, which followed the question.  Suppose that two random children were selected, and both children were seen to be girls.  This is as opposed to examining all of the genders at once, and noticing that there are less than 6 boys.

Then, to attack the problem of the chances that the total number of girls is $x$, where $x \in \{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, I would proceed as follows:

Let $E_x$ denote the event that there are exactly $x$ girls. 
Let $F$ denote the event that two randomly inspected children were seen to be girls.

Then, I would calculate $p(E_x|F)$ as follows:

Let $\displaystyle T_k = \left[\frac{\binom{7}{k}}{2^7} \times \frac{\binom{k}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}}\right].$

Then, $\displaystyle p(E_x|F) = \frac{p(E_x F)}{p(F)} = \frac{T_x}{\sum_{k=2}^7 T_k}.$